# Hide empty slots in nested array using AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, hide

In my ionic app, I want to show a cart. My problem is empty objects in my nested array.

My array look like this:

```
array [0:{id:0,
          name:meal,  
          item:[0:{id:0,name:pizza0,count:1},
                2:{id:2,name:pizza2,count:3}]}
       1:{id:1,
          name:meal,  
          item:[0:{id:0,name:drink0,count:1},
                1:{id:1,name:drink1,count:5}]}
       ]
```

My html code look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="cart in carts">
    <ion-item class="item-stable">
      &nbsp;<!-- breaking space-->
      {{cart.name}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-repeat="item in cart.item track by $index">
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="removeFromCart(item,cart.id)"></ion-delete-button>
        {{item.count}}x {{item.name}} - {{item.length}}
    <ion-item>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

I try to hide the empty arrays with ng-if:

1. `ng-if="cart.item.length > 0"`
2. `ng-if="item.name"`

With the first, no item shows (probably because cart.item.length is undefined).
With the second all items are shown.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to hide empty arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use safe navigation operator with ngIf directive.
use ngIf in div tag like this:

*ng-If="item?"

This will only hide the empty items and only show items with data in it.

Comment: thanks for responding so fast. "item?" seems not working in ionic. it gives me an "Unexpected end of expression" - error. I try it again with "item.name" and now it works...for that i change a bit the html code. but "item.name" is not the best way to check if array is empty...is there another way?

Comment: i try it with ng-if="item !== undefined" and it works, well. Should be the proper solution thand "item.name"

Comment: item:[0:{id:0,name:pizza0,count:1},
                2:{id:2,name:pizza2,count:3}]
For this array item, id 1 is undefined that's y its working.
If item array is like this
item:[0:{id:0,name:pizza0,count:1},
1:{id:1,name:,count:}],
                2:{id:2,name:pizza2,count:3}]
Then item.name? or item.count? will work.